# bcryptjs compare not working as expected. Always returns false even after immediatly checking

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

I've been stumped on this for a bit and am not sure why the bcryptjs.compare method isn't working for me. Here is my hash function right before I save into the DB. I added the compare here before I submit to check and it was still false. Any reason why this is failing?

````
userSchema.pre('save', async function(next){
    if(!this.isModified('password')){
        return next();
     } 
    
    var original = (' ' + this.password).slice(1);
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password,10);
    
    console.log(await bcrypt.compare(original,this.password)+": trying online test")
    next();
})```
````

Comment: I solved this issue.... In my modal for passwords, I had a toLowercase  option set for mongoose and it was corrupting the password and not making it match the hash. Be weary of that when using this method.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the password and then add a whitespace in front of it, when you assign `original` its value. Which of course is different from the value of the password.

Let's assume, that the password is `"Password"`

That would give us `" assword"` as the value of `original`, which is obviously different from `"Password"` and thus `brypt.compare` will always return false, because you compare two different things.